# Tag Synonym Request: [file] -> [files]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I don't see any difference between [file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/file) and [files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/files).

Alternatively, blacklist? They don't seem particularly descriptive, and I doubt anyone considers themselves an expert on the topic of files and wants to subscribe to these tags.

Comment: We seem to have forgotten about this one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Done.

Just merged [file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/file) → [files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/files).